# Continuous curves in metric spaces

Tags: continuity, curves

“Introductory real analysis” by Kolmogorov and Fomin defines continuous curves by the equivalence of continuous functions by the following.

> Let $R$ be a metric space and suppose $a’≤b’$ and $a’’≤b’’$. Two continuous functions $f:[a’,b’]→R$ and $g:[a'',b'']→R$ are said to be equivalent if there exist two continuous nondecreasing functions $φ(t),ψ(t)$, defined on the same interval $[a,b]$ such that $φ(a)=a’,φ(b)=b’,ψ(a)=a'',ψ(b)=b''$, and $f(φ(t))=g(ψ(t))$ for all $t∈[a,b]$. ”

However, I don’t know why this relation satisfies transitivity.
When $f$ and $g$ are equivalent and $g$ and $h$ are equivalent, I don’t know how to define $φ$ and $ψ$ corresponding to the equivalence between $f$ and $h$.
Please help me.

Comment: Please quote the definition here instead of asking people to download a PDF of dubious legality. Also, I don't understand what you mean by "construct specific functions showing transitivity".

Comment: Let R be a metric space and suppose a’<b’ and a”<b”.Two continuous functions f:[a’,b’]→R and g:[a”,b”]→R are said to be equivalent if there exist two continuous nondecreasing functions φ(t),ψ(t),defined on the same interval [a,b] such that φ(a)=a’,φ(b)=b’,ψ(a)=a”,ψ(b)=b”, and f(φ(t))=g(ψ(t)) for all t∈[a,b].

Comment: When f and g are equivalent and g and h are equivalent, I don’t know how to define φ and ψ corresponding to the equivalence between f and h.

Comment: Partial answer: If $f$ and $g$ are equivalent, then we have functions $\phi_1,\psi_1$ such that $f\circ\phi_1 = g\circ\psi_1$; similarly, if $g$ and $h$ are equivalent then we have $\phi_2,\psi_2$ such that $g\circ\phi_2 = h\circ\psi_2$. Now we only need to find functions $\tau_1,\tau_2:[a,b]\to[a,b]$ such that $\psi_1\circ\tau_1 = \phi_2\circ\tau_2$. If so, then $f\circ\phi_1\circ\tau_1 = g\circ\psi_1\circ\tau_1 = g\circ\phi_2\circ\tau_2 = h\circ\psi_2\circ\tau_2$, therefore $f$ and $h$ are equivalent. I'm pretty sure this is possible but not sure of the exact construction.

Comment: This amounts to showing that $\psi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are equivalent as curves in $[a'',b'']$. Maybe that gives some ideas.

Comment: I don’t come up with the ideas.